# CSS transform flip effect, Chrome problematic

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transforms

I've been working on a 3D flip book effect (alias flip card effect) in Firefox.

Then, I tested it in Chrome (*Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit), macOS Mojave*) and it didn't run as expected: At the beginning, the back book cover is in the foreground. Then, the rest of the animation (`transition`) runs as expected (see Firefox).

I thought I can fix this in Chrome by setting `backface-visibility: hidden`. I tried a few things but nothing worked.

**DEMO**: [https://jsbin.com/yekovimuku](https://jsbin.com/yekovimuku/1/edit?html,css,output)

HTML:

```
<div class="book">
  <div class="book-wrapper">
    <img class="book-cover-front" src="...">
    <img class="book-spine" src="...">
    <img class="book-cover-back" src="...">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.book {
  /* just assumed a random container size */
  width: 399px;
  height: 571px;

  -webkit-perspective: 2636px;
  perspective: 2636px;
}
.book-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  position: relative;

  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  transition: transform ease-out 2.6s;
}
.book:hover .book-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.book-cover-front, .book-cover-back, .book-spine {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.book-cover-front, .book-cover-back {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.book-cover-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(30px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(30px);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(30px);
}
.book-spine {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;

  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-80deg) translateX(-15px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-80deg) translateX(-15px);
  transform: rotateY(-80deg) translateX(-15px);
}
```

One way might be to put the `img.book-cover-back` in a extra `div-container` and rotate it then back (`transform: rotateX(180deg)`).

Info: The set `width`, `height`, `max-width`, `max-height` looks like a mess but it works well in the container, and I don't think it's part of the problem in Chrome.

Please help me to get this working in Chrome, too.

Comment: `@Maximilian` There is need to wrap image by DIV like `<div class="book-cover-front"><img src=""></div>` and write css for image like `.book-wrapper img{width: 100%; height: 100%;}` and use `backface-visibility: hidden` on `.book-spine` class. So after do this changes it will work.

Answer (score 0):

My below snippet I have wrapped `IMG tag` inside `DIV tag` and there is need to add `backface-visibility: hidden` on `.book-spine` class because of after flip then remove single line show as base of `book-spine` `image` on backside image on right side and also I have added prefix for more browsers compatibility.
I hope this below snippet will help you lot.

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{margin-top: 3em;}
.book {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 399px;
  height: 571px;
  -webkit-perspective: 2636px;
    -moz-perspective: 2636px;
      perspective: 2636px;
}
.book-wrapper {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: transform ease-out 2.6s;
    -moz-transition: transform ease-out 2.6s;
      -o-transition: transform ease-out 2.6s;
        transition: transform ease-out 2.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.book:hover .book-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.book-cover-front, .book-cover-back, .book-spine{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.book-cover-front, .book-cover-back{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.book-cover-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(30px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(30px);
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(30px);
}
.book-spine {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-80deg) translateX(-15px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-80deg) translateX(-15px);
      transform: rotateY(-80deg) translateX(-15px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.book-wrapper img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <div class="book-wrapper">
    <div class="book-cover-front"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/L1i9cve.png"></div>
    <div class="book-spine"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/wmA6031.png"></div>
    <div class="book-cover-back"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/oNfGLOw.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```